# Having dynamic name's in array AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, dynamic

I'm having issues with AS3. I'm trying to get the items i put in the array to have an dynamic name (ex. lines[k]) so that when i want to call on them later i can call them by their number instead of calling them all at the time

I've found some tutorials with dynamic array names on the website but i'm unsure how to fit them in the code because I keep getting error's.

At the moment this is my code:

```
var numPoints:Number = 0;       //  Number of points placed. 
                                //  No dragging will work until all 7 points are placed.

//  Set max & min stage coordinates that the points can be dragged, and make the point diameters settable.
var xMax:Number = 700;
var xMin:Number = 5;
var yMax:Number = 500;
var yMin:Number = 5;
var o = 0;
var circleWidth:Number = 5;

//  Boolean variables to indicate that dragging is happening so that the appropriate point follows the mouse
//  on the MOUSE_MOVE event.
var isDragging1:Boolean = false;
var isDragging2:Boolean = false;
var isDragging3:Boolean = false;
var isDragging4:Boolean = false;
var isDragging5:Boolean = false;
var isDragging6:Boolean = false;
var isDragging7:Boolean = false;

//  The drawBoard is a rectangle on which the triangle will be drawn.  Colors are settable here. To change size,
//  change the variables xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax above.
var drawBoard:Sprite = new Sprite();
drawBoard.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
drawBoard.graphics.beginFill(0xCCCCCC);
drawBoard.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, xMax - xMin, yMax - yMin);
drawBoard.graphics.endFill();
drawBoard.x = xMin;
drawBoard.y = yMin;


// Array (Where "lines goes into")
var q:int = 0;
var shapeArray:Array/* of flash.display.Shape */ = [] /* of flash.display.Shape */;
var lines:Shape = new Shape();

//  Add a default drop shadow filter to the drawBoard
drawBoard.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];

//  This rectangle will listen for mouse clicks in order to construct the three vertices of the triangle.
drawBoard.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, placePoint);

//  Put on the stage the board on which the triangle will be drawn.
stage.addChild(drawBoard);

//  The filled triangle consists of three lines drawn between the points. It is updated     on MOUSE_MOVE once 
//  dragging starts.

drawBoard.addChild(lines);


//  The stage will listen for events involving dragging so that the dragging will continue to work even after
//  the mouse has rolled off of the drawBoard region.
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseUpdate);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);

// Button 2 (Left)
bttn_add.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toevoegen);

// Button 3 (Middle)
bttn_show.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showit);


// adding shape to array

function toevoegen(e:Event):void
{

    // adding
    shapeArray.push( lines );
    numPoints = 0;
    trace("Done pushing")

}

// Shape show

function showit(e:Event):void
{
    trace(shapeArray.length);
  if (!shapeArray || shapeArray.length == 0){
//      shapeArray.push( lines );
trace("array is leeg")
    return; // nothing to do here
    }


  const lines:Shape = shapeArray[o] as Shape;
   if (lines && ! lines.parent) {
       o++;
       trace ("tracer"+ o);
}// show it
    drawBoard.addChild(lines)
          //shapeArray.push( lines );
          numPoints = 0;


    trace()
}



//  We add 7 points to the stage but we do not add the graphics yet.  We do specify listeners
//  at this time so when they are all placed, we will be able to drag them.

var point1:Sprite = new Sprite();
point1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging1);
drawBoard.addChild(point1);

var point2:Sprite = new Sprite();
point2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging2);
drawBoard.addChild(point2);

var point3:Sprite = new Sprite();
point3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging3);
drawBoard.addChild(point3);

var point4:Sprite = new Sprite();
point4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging4);
drawBoard.addChild(point4);

var point5:Sprite = new Sprite();
point5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging5);
drawBoard.addChild(point5);

var point6:Sprite = new Sprite();
point6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging6);
drawBoard.addChild(point6);

var point7:Sprite = new Sprite();
point7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging7);
drawBoard.addChild(point7);




//  The reset button will stop all dragging, remove all children of drawBoard, and set numPoints back to 0.

btnReset.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);

function reset(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var i:Number;
    var n:Number = drawBoard.numChildren;

    isDragging1 = false;
    isDragging2 = false;
    isDragging3 = false;
    isDragging4 = false;
    isDragging5 = false;
    isDragging6 = false;
    isDragging7 = false;

    point1.graphics.clear();
    point2.graphics.clear();
    point3.graphics.clear();
    point4.graphics.clear();
    point5.graphics.clear();
    point6.graphics.clear();
    point7.graphics.clear();

    /*
    drawBoard.removeChild(point1);
    drawBoard.removeChild(point2);
    drawBoard.removeChild(point3);
    drawBoard.removeChild(point4);
    drawBoard.removeChild(point5);
    drawBoard.removeChild(point6);
    drawBoard.removeChild(point7);
   */
    //lines.graphics.clear();
    drawBoard.removeChild(lines);
    numPoints = 0;
    trace(numPoints);




}

//  The next function is executed when the mouse is moved.  Note that if all points are not placed and nothing
//  is being dragged, this function does nothing.
function mouseUpdate(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) { 
        if (isDragging1) {
            point1.x = goodX(evt.stageX);       //  Set x- & y-coordinates.  See below for definition of 
            point1.y = goodY(evt.stageY);       //      functions goodX & goodY
            //lines.graphics.clear();             //  Remove lines shape and redraw it 


            drawLines();                        //      with updated coordinates.
        }
            if (isDragging2) {
            point2.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point2.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            //lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }
            if (isDragging3) {
            point3.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point3.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            //lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }

        if (isDragging4) {
            point4.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point4.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            //lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }

        if (isDragging5) {
            point5.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point5.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            //lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }

        if (isDragging6) {
            point6.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point6.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            //lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }

        if (isDragging7) {
            point7.x = goodX(evt.stageX);
            point7.y = goodY(evt.stageY);
            //lines.graphics.clear();
            drawLines();
        }

        evt.updateAfterEvent();
    }
}


/*  This function chooses the appropriate x-coordinate for a dragged point.  
    If thisX is in the draggable region, then we return it.  Otherwise, we return the max or min x value, 
    depending on which side of the draggable region thisX is on.
*/

function goodX(thisX:Number):Number {
    if (thisX < xMin) {
        return (xMin);
    }
    if (thisX > (xMax - circleWidth)) {
        return (xMax - circleWidth);
    }
    return (thisX);
}


//  This function chooses the appropriate y-coordinate for a dragged point in a manner     similar to the previous function. 

function goodY(thisY:Number):Number {
    if (thisY < yMin) {
        return (yMin);
    }
    if (thisY > (yMax - circleWidth)) {
        return (yMax - circleWidth);
    }
    return thisY;
}

// This function manages the placement of points until all 7 points are placed. 
function placePoint(evt:MouseEvent):void {

    //var point = new Sprite();
    //array.push(point);

    if (numPoints == 0) {
        point1.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point1.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point1.graphics.endFill();
        point1.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point1.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point1.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 1;
    }
    else if(numPoints == 1) {
        point2.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point2.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point2.graphics.endFill();
        point2.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point2.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point2.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 2;
    }
    else if (numPoints == 2) {
        point3.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point3.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point3.graphics.endFill();
        point3.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point3.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point3.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 3;
        //lines.graphics.clear();
        //drawBoard.removeChild(lines);

    }

    else if (numPoints == 3) {
        point4.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point4.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point4.graphics.endFill();
        point4.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point4.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point4.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 4;
        //lines.graphics.clear();
        //drawBoard.removeChild(lines);
    }

    else if (numPoints == 4) {
        point5.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point5.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point5.graphics.endFill();
        point5.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point5.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point5.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 5;
        //lines.graphics.clear();
        //drawBoard.removeChild(lines);
    }

    else if (numPoints == 5) {
        point6.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point6.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point6.graphics.endFill();
        point6.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point6.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point6.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
       numPoints = 6;
        //lines.graphics.clear();
        //drawBoard.removeChild(lines);
    }

    else if (numPoints == 6) {
        point7.graphics.beginFill(0x7777FF);
        point7.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, circleWidth/2);
        point7.graphics.endFill();
        point7.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        point7.x = drawBoard.mouseX;
        point7.y = drawBoard.mouseY;
        numPoints = 7;
        q++;
            //shapeArray.push( lines );

        //lines.graphics.clear();
        //drawBoard.removeChild(lines);

        drawLines();
        //verplaatsen();
        trace(numPoints);
    }
}

//  Draws the 7 lines between the points with appropriate fill and adds a drop shadow.
function drawLines():void {
        lines.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
        lines.graphics.beginFill(0xFF7777);
        lines.graphics.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point3.x, point3.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point4.x, point4.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point5.x, point5.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point6.x, point6.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point7.x, point7.y);
        lines.graphics.lineTo(point1.x, point1.y);
        lines.graphics.endFill();
        lines.filters = [ new DropShadowFilter() ];
        trace(lines)
        trace ("geval"+ o)
}

//  The next functions "turn on" dragging for the point that is clicked, as long as all 7 points have
//  been placed.
function startDragging1(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging1 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging2(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging2 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging3(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging3 = true;
    }
}
function startDragging4(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging4 = true;
    }
}

    function startDragging5(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging5 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging6(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging6 = true;
    }
}

function startDragging7(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging7 = true;
    }
}

//  Turns off dragging. This function is called when the mouse button is released anywhere on the stage.
function stopDragging(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (numPoints == 7) {
        isDragging1 = false;
        isDragging2 = false;
        isDragging3 = false;
        isDragging4 = false;
        isDragging5 = false;
        isDragging6 = false;
        isDragging7 = false;

    }
}
/*
function verplaatsen():void{
        lines.x = 0;
        lines.x = 100;
        lines.y = 300;

}*/
```

I apologize if my code is messy / sloppy I've been trying all day and a bit sleep deprived now.

Any help will be greatly apreciated

(As a side not: Is their an fast way to put those 4 spaces infront to create code blocks on this website?)

Comment: @Code formatting: sometime this helps: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks (look at answer with 54 upvotes)

Comment: Thank you for that link, Could you also please elaborate why the question got downvoted

Comment: I can only suggest and I would say it is maybe because of this huge amount of code. Could you use a debugger/ at which specific steps do you get which errors? Then it is easier to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into how array works, from your code I can see you are just using different variables to hold all the sprites and checking different variables inside functions like isDraging1,2,3,4,5.

Here is some code to get you started.

```
public var mySprites:Array = [];

public function init():void
{
   for (var i:int = 0; i<10; ++i)
   {
       createSprite();
   } 
}

public function createSprite():void
{
   var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
   sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICK,onSpriteClicked);
   addChild(sprite);
   mySprites.push(sprite);
}

public function onSpriteClicked(e:MouseEvent):void
{
   trace("You clicked sprite : "+mySprites.indexOf(e.target as Sprite));
   // you can use the sprite here 
   var clickedSprite:Sprite = e.target as Sprite;
   if(clickedSprite) 
   {
      //do something with sprite
   }
}
```